# Using "set --" in shell script results in "bad number"

Tags: shell, ksh

Using an existing shell script and attempt to obtain an understanding of 
exactly what it is doing. 

The first 7 lines were extracted out, but when I run a test, it fails with a "bad number" error. 

Here is the code from the script.

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo $2
DUMMY_INPUT=$2
set -- $DUMMY_INPUT
shift
VAR1=$1;shift;shift
echo $VAR1
```

This was the first test.

```
 > ./runThis.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
  arg2
 ./runThis.sh[6]: shift: (null): bad number
```

Based on the error, another test was run using numbers only but the same error appears.

```
 > ./runThis.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 2
 ./runThis.sh[6]: shift: (null): bad number
```

As a test, the "set --" command was commented out and it now works.

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo $2
DUMMY_INPUT=$2
#set -- $DUMMY_INPUT  <-----Comment out this line
shift
VAR1=$1;shift;shift
echo $VAR1
```

```
 > ./runThis.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
 arg2
 arg2
```

```
 > ./runThis.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 2
 2
```

Is the implementation of the "set" command wrong?
Any idea why it is failing?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

After reading the response, I have a better understanding....

```
 #! /bin/ksh
 echo $2
 DUMMY_INPUT=$@
 set -- $DUMMY_INPUT
 shift
 VAR1=$1;shift;shift
 echo $VAR1
```

If I followed correctly, the "set" command sets the input arguments to be the content of the DUMMY_INPUT which was set to only a single value in the original code. 

This code change sets it to the entire string of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `shift` in `ksh` but there are no positional parameters defined, you get the error

```
ksh: shift: (null): bad number
```

For example:

```
> set -- a b
> echo $1
a
> shift
> echo $1 
b
> shift
> echo $1

> shift
ksh: shift: (null): bad number
```

Comment: Are you saying in my example there aren't enough parameters? Even using "> ./runThis.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14" fails with the same error.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now.